# Is there a JSON library that can serialize Proxy objects?

Tags: java, json, proxy, gson, active-objects

Using ActiveObjects as my ORM and Gson as my JSON processor.

Ran into a problem going toJson from
persisted objects.  The problem is that my persisted class is actually
an Interface and AO is proxying that object under the hood.  Here's
some sample code:

```
    Venue venue = manager.get(Venue.class, id);
    gson.toJson(venue);
```

Comes up with this exception:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Expecting parameterized type,
got interface java.lang.reflect.InvocationHandler.
 Are you missing the use of TypeToken idiom?
 See http://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Serializing-and...
```

Because venue.getClass().getName() gives:

$Proxy228

I've tried a few solutions in various combinations:

```
    gsonBuilder.registerTypeAdapter(Venue.class, newVenueSerializer());
    Type listType = new TypeToken<Venue>() {}.getType();
```

Nothing has worked so far and I'm using a wonky field-by-field workaround.  Any suggestions?  I'm not married to Gson, so if there's an alternative library that can do this I'd be happy to use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Flex JSON](http://flexjson.sourceforge.net/) should work - it will use the bean property introspector to pull the object, and I assume the proxy class implements those properly.

Comment: Will give it a shot and report back.  Thanks!

Comment: Doesn't look like the proxy class is implementing any introspectors.  If it did, though, you'de have been right.  So, you win.

Answer (score 0):

Also check out the [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/).